# SPFx:: pnp js :: Delete selected file from client web part using Reactjs

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-framework, pnp-js-core, document-management, reactjs

I have a SPFx client web part with documents from library.

Now when I select item/row, I need to perform different operations like Delete/Check-in/Check-out based on the button events.

I need to show a little doc icon indicating file check out/Chech in.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what have you tried ? what is causing a problem in your implementation ? Can you share what you have done so that we can help you ? This is quite broad

Comment: I implemented SPFx web part and displayed data in it. But taxonomy, user fields are null. And I'm not sure of implementation of delete/check-in/check out features.

Comment: You need to expand this fields, e.g. `?$expand=AssignedTo&$select=*,AssignedTo/Title` and the checkout for example you can see this in the properties on the file `/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + docUrl  + "')/checkOutType",` . If you provide more informations requested from @GautamSheth we can give you a more specific answer ;-)